# Difference between prevState and ...state

Tags: reactjs

I have a theoretical question:

What is the difference between these 2 react statements:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  age:0
})

setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, age: prevState.age + 1}) )
```

and

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  age:0
})

setState({...state, age: state.age + 1})
```

?

Comment: It's explained in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous Call `setState` twice and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state updates asynchronous. So to be sure you use the actual state you should pass the function:

```
setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, age: prevState.age + 1}) )
```

If it doesn't matter to work with the actual state you can pass simple object like:

```
setState({...state, age: state.age + 1})
```

For more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64879685/react-setting-state-using-prevstate