# React setting state using ...prevState

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I have this state in my React application:

```js
const [city, setCity] = useState({
  name: "",
  id: ""
});
```

I'm trying to change the state like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setCity(prevState => ({...prevState, id: 'test'}))
}, [])
```

Doing this I get an error in WebStorm when hovering over the code:

> Argument type function(any): {id: string} is not assignable to
> parameter type ((prevState: {name: string, id: string}) => {name:
> string, id: string}) | {name: string, id: string} ...   Type string is
> not assignable to type undefined

Why do I get this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: can't reproduce with similar code. What IDE version do you use? could you share a complete code snippet the issue can be repeated with?

Comment: @lena, i use WebStorm 2020.2.2 x64

Comment: works fine for me in 2020.2.2; please provide a complete code snippet